# How use Scripting.FileSystemObject in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, json, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I know that ActiveXObject is no longer in Microsoft Edge. So how can i use the FileSystemObject in Microsoft Edge? 
I'm trying to make a Microsoft Edge plugin that obtains the html code of a page web and writes it into a .txt in my local file system
The following code is this:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var f1 = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\htmltext.txt",true);
var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
f1.WriteLine(markup);
f1.Close();});
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX is not supported in Microsoft Edge, and Microsoft Edge doesn't support plugin either.

You could consider write an extension for Microsoft Edge, use [Native Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging) to pass html code from extension to your native app, then write the info into file system from native app.

Comment: Sorry for my bad vocabulary. I mean extension (i supposed that extension and plugin means the same). Thanks i will try with Native Messaging